# string splitting logic in C programing

Tags: c

Could you please provide me some code or solution how to split the below string in C programming

Sample string :

`SMABCDEFGHIJK,887276617459,5,552612260849779,552612260840646,552612260843632,552612260843525,552612260846817`

Output needed :

`552612260849779,552612260840646,552612260843632,552612260843525,552612260846817`

Basically for the input string we would need to Ignore first 3 positions and want rest of the string in different variable.
The positions to ignore and  delimiter values will get the from the database table label.
So, If someone help me to give the logic that would be very helpful

Comment: You can use `strchr()` to find successive comma delimiters. You can't use `strtok()` because it will break up the rest of the string, unless you want to put it back together.

Comment: I think [`strtok`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) will send you down the right path.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil same as 99.9999999999999999% questions asked here

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you do not need to split the string. Simply ignore everything before the n-th occurrence of the delimiter.

```
char *ignoreFisrstN(const char *str, int delim, size_t ignoreCount)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    while(ignoreCount--)
    {
        if((str = strchr(str, delim))) str++;
        else break;
    }
    if(str)
    {
        result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        if(result) strcpy(result, str);
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *s = "SMABCDEFGHIJK,887276617459,5,552612260849779,552612260840646,552612260843632,552612260843525,552612260846817";

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char *r = ignoreFisrstN(s, ',', i);

        printf("%zu: `%s`\n", i, r ? r : "NULL");
        free(r);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xWe74sY46